# How to include all custom object property in MVC 4 HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model with a custom object. On the initial get, I populate Foo and use a couple of Foo's properties.

On the post, I find that Foo on the view model is null.

I could add to my view, `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Foo.Id)` which could ensure that a Foo is populated with at least an Id, but then I could need to add similar code for all of the properties.

Is there a way to send back the complete object?

```
public class RequestModel
    {
        public Foo Foo{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
   //Populate Foo here using EF and add it to the model
   var model = new RequestModel { Foo = foo };    
   return View(model);
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? id, RequestModel model)
{
   return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.Application.Name)
```

etc

Comment: Could you add the code from your view and controller?

Comment: I've updated the question. I guess my question is really whether a VM should expose EF objects, or if the controller should just map the simple values onto the view.

Comment: Why do you want to send all `Foo` properties back to the action?

Comment: Because I want to use the object in the controller post event and I don't want to guess if a proprty is null by default or because I missed a mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a view model with the properties you want to your solution. Put your validations etc on it and use that to move your data between your page and controller then map the properties to your EF object.